# Error while calling AsyncTask within a gesture listener

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, gesture

Right now, I have an Activity that displays 10 listings from a `JSON` array. Next, on the swipe of an `ImageView`, I want to clear the `ListView` and display the next 10 (as a "next page" type thing). So, right now I do this

```
    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getBaseContext()) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
                    //clear adapter
            adapter.clear();
                    //get listings 10-20
            startLoop = 10; 
            endLoop = 20;
                    //call asynctask to display locations
        FillLocations myFill = new FillLocations();
        myFill.execute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

and when I swipe it diisplays ONE item and I get this error
`Error Parsing Data android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`
What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView listView;
int startLoop, endLoop;
TextView test;
ArrayList<Location> arrayOfLocations;
LocationAdapter adapter;

ImageView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startLoop = 0;
    endLoop = 10;
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // Construct the data source
    arrayOfLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    adapter = new LocationAdapter(this, arrayOfLocations);

    FillLocations myFill = new FillLocations();
    myFill.execute();

    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getBaseContext()) {
        @Override
        public void onSwipeLeft() {
            adapter.clear();

            startLoop = 10;
            endLoop = 20;
        FillLocations myFill = new FillLocations();
        myFill.execute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Left",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}

private class FillLocations extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, String> {
    String msg = "Done";

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress.show();
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        String result = "";
        InputStream isr = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://americanfarmstands.com/places/");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();
            // resultView.setText("connected");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();

            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = startLoop; i < endLoop; i++) {

                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), i,
                //         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                final JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // counter++;

                String initialURL = "http://afs.spotcontent.com/img/Places/Icons/";
                final String updatedURL = initialURL + json.getInt("ID")
                        + ".jpg";
                Bitmap bitmap2 = null;

                try {
                    bitmap2 = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(updatedURL)
                                    .getContent());

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    adapter.add(new Location(bitmap2, json
                            .getString("PlaceTitle"), json
                            .getString("PlaceDetails"), json
                            .getString("PlaceDistance"), json
                            .getString("PlaceUpdatedTime")));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
        }
        return msg;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        // Attach the adapter to a ListView
        //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        progress.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Location Adapter:

```
public class LocationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Location> {
public LocationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Location> locations) {
   super(context, R.layout.item_location, locations);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // Get the data item for this position
   Location location = getItem(position);    
   // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_location, parent, false);
   }

   // Lookup view for data population
   TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
   TextView tvDetails = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDetails);
   TextView tvDistance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDistance);
   TextView tvHours = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHours);
   ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);

   // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
   tvName.setText(location.name);
   tvDetails.setText(location.details);
   tvDistance.setText(location.distance);
   tvHours.setText(location.hours);
   ivIcon.setImageBitmap(location.icon);
   // Return the completed view to render on screen
   return convertView;
}
}
```

EDIT: Updated Code:

for (int i = startLoop; i < endLoop; i++) {

```
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), i,
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                final JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // counter++;

                String initialURL = "http://afs.spotcontent.com/img/Places/Icons/";
                final String updatedURL = initialURL + json.getInt("ID")
                        + ".jpg";
                final Bitmap bitmap2 =BitmapFactory
                        .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(updatedURL)
                        .getContent());

                //try {
                //  bitmap2 = BitmapFactory
                //          .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(updatedURL)
                //                  .getContent());

                //} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                //  e.printStackTrace();
                //} catch (IOException e) {
                //  e.printStackTrace();
                //}
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            adapter.add(new Location(bitmap2, json
                                    .getString("PlaceTitle"), json
                                    .getString("PlaceDetails"), json
                                    .getString("PlaceDistance"), json
                                    .getString("PlaceUpdatedTime")));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: This is the only error I get plus `Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

Comment: then post the LocationAdapter

Comment: updated with location adapter

Comment: `This is the only error I get` which makes sense since your catch block only contains a log, when it should contain `printStackTrace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter must be updated from the **UI thread**.

You should change your AsyncTask into `AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<Location>>`, and have the loop in on `doInBackground()` create a collection of `Location` and **return** it (instead of directly changing the adapter).

Finally, in `onPostExecute(List<Location> result)`, do:

```
adapter.clear();
for (Location location : result)
    adapter.add(location);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is clearly saying that you are trying to update View from a different thread(`doInBackground`) that catch an exception `CalledFromWrongThreadException`.

This line is the cause of the problem

`adapter.add(new Location(bitmap2, json
                            .getString("PlaceTitle"), json
                            .getString("PlaceDetails"), json
                            .getString("PlaceDistance"), json
                            .getString("PlaceUpdatedTime")));`

that it should be called in the Main thread.

**solution:**

Call the main thread and update the adapter from there

**example:**

```
try {
                   final Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(updatedURL)
                                    .getContent());
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.add(new Location(bitmap2, json
                            .getString("PlaceTitle"), json
                            .getString("PlaceDetails"), json
                            .getString("PlaceDistance"), json
                            .getString("PlaceUpdatedTime")));

            }
        });

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: When I do this, it says I need to make bitmap2 final, but when I do so it throws another error

Comment: when I do try {
      bitmap2 = BitmapFactory
        .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(updatedURL)
          .getContent());  it says `the final local variable bitmap2 cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment`

Comment: So when I add this, it basically tells me to add "final" to bitmap2 and then when I do it tells me to remove "final" lol

Comment: @user1282637 that error is that you are initializing bitmap2 variable twice.

Comment: It gives another error on bitmap2 in the RunOnUiThread if I do this. I got it working (for the most part) and my updated code is in the main post now. Could you see if you think its good now? Thanks

Comment: Not in the updated code, but I no longer have the try statement. Is this ok?

Comment: thank you so much, will upvote, this did help but matiash's answer worked more effectively

Answer (score 0):

Move this bunch of code to `onPostExecute`

```
protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
    try {
            adapter.add(new Location(bitmap2, json
                    .getString("PlaceTitle"), json
                    .getString("PlaceDetails"), json
                    .getString("PlaceDistance"), json
                    .getString("PlaceUpdatedTime")));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    progress.dismiss();
}
```

Make `Bitmap` a class variable.

Comment: Do not add to adapter now. Store it in some temporary storage. Populate `Adapter` in `onPostExecute`